# How do i make cefsharp use a certin search engine

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

So using my CefSharp browser in I'm also using a TextBox For The AddressBar and I was wanting to add a feature where when I type a search like (how to make a cake) or something, let me explain. when I open google chrome on the top where your websites show up like https://bing.com/ for example, when I want to search how to do something or a specific word or more than one word it just stays at a blank page state and doesn't load my search engine the only way that you can search words and URLs if you are at the bing homepage and you click the search bar on the site. if you would like to see what my address bar looks like [Click Here to view the imege](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9fhA.png). the bottom line is just I would like to have an address bar that can search words and URLs, it can already search URLs tho

some code I used in the examples given are

```
// run search if unknown URL
newUrl = SearchURL + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);

// load URL
CurBrowser.Load(newUrl);

// set URL in UI
SetFormURL(newUrl);
```

so I copied some of the code for the example given in the comments and i put the code in Form1.Load il show you where i put it

```
    // run search if unknown URL
    newUrl = SearchURL + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);

    // load URL
    CurBrowser.Load(newUrl);

    private ChromiumWebBrowser Chrome;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        //initialza
        Chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(textBox1.Text);
        Chrome.Load("https://bing.com");
        this.AcceptButton = this.button7;
        Chrome.DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandler();
        this.pContainer.Controls.Add(Chrome);
        Chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        InitAppIcon();
        InitTooltips(this.Controls);
        InitHotkeys();
        Chrome.AddressChanged += Chrome_AddressChanged;
    }
```

the code that I gave to form1 is mine, the code in the example is at the top

Comment: You basically have to write your own. At it's simplest it's just parse the text box value into a uri, if it's invalid append it to your search engine url. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.iswellformeduristring?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.trycreate?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I don't know what to change in the code, I'm a beginner in programming I know a lot but I don't know the advanced stuff. oh and also is this for windows form apps

Comment: i also don't know where to apply the code, do I double click my browser control or my address bar

Comment: https://github.com/sharpbrowser/SharpBrowser/blob/master/src/MainForm.cs#L253 should give a rough example.

Comment: None of the code in the examples given in the post worked

Comment: I don't think I put the code in the right location

Comment: Edit your question and add the code you've used.

Comment: SOme of the code i used in the example are // run search if unknown URL
     newUrl = SearchURL + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url)

Comment: Edit your question and provide the exact code you are using. Saying some of the code doesn't help me help you.

Comment: so one peice of the code i used was colored in yellow and that line was '// run search if unknown URL
     newUrl = SearchURL + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url)'

Comment: // load URL
   CurBrowser.Load(newUrl);

   // set URL in UI
   SetFormURL(newUrl);

Comment: Again please **edit** your code and post the exact code, adding code in comments isn't ideal in this example. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks for how to format your code

Comment: ok I formated the code I put it in my post read it at the top I updated it so you can better understand

Comment: You don't seem to be parsing the uri. See https://github.com/sharpbrowser/SharpBrowser/blob/master/src/MainForm.cs#L238 if the TryCreate methid returns false then append the value from your address bar to the search url. If it's successfully then directly load.

Comment: I don't know what parts of the code I need and, where do I put the parts of the code at do i double click my textbox, or do I double click my search button or put it in my Form1_load or something?

Comment: Before you call Load, you validate the value from your text box using TryCreate, if it fails then you build a search query url and pass that to Load. It's really really simple.

Comment: To Give you a better example of what im going for ill give you my project file and then you will know what programming language I'm using and can you put the code in it because i dont know where to put it: LINK: http://www.mediafire.com/file/qmst8s6nvf3vqaq/My_Browser_Project.zip/file

Comment: Sorry, I don't download zip files from unknown sources.

Comment: oh ok, i dont know how to explain it to you so you can understand what i mean, im a beginner at programming and i realy wanted to make a browser and so far its going good apart form issues with it

Comment: Fundamentally `CefSharp` doesn't provide an search engine functionality, it's up to you to implement it yourself. Whatever you pass to the `Load(url)` method will be attempted to load as a web page. You can hook like the `LoadError` event to maybe perform some redirect to a search engine, past that it's really up to you to implement. You need to break your problem down into smaller steps, first is determine if text typed in your address bar is a valid url. If it's not a valid url then you can build up your own url.

Comment: Using google search as an example, if the user typed in cefsharp, you'd validate that, it's not a url, so you'd then load https://www.google.com/search?q=cefsharp You need to html encode params to get the spaces etc if the user has entered any, there's an example in the first link I sent for that. Final attempt from me to explain a very basic implementation. Best of luck

Comment: i dont know how that's why i made this post because i was asking for code that was already done and was in .NET Framework 4.7.2 because i was going to use that code and grow my programming skills by looking at how it works and then trying to re-create it

Comment: Sorry if i am wasting your time.

Comment: Download and debug the https://github.com/sharpbrowser/SharpBrowser project to get a better understanding of how that project implemented it.

Comment: I already did and the code isn't blocks like mine is its .NET Core code not .NET Framework

Comment: There might be some minor differences, the fundamentals are the same. You can run a .Net assembly under .Net Core, they're very compatible.

Comment: So there the same thing, i dont know what all the code means and I tried to bring bits and pieces of the code to my browser project and changed some of the names it just wouldn't stop making more and more errors I changed the Project name in the pieces of code I moved over and it got worse. and even if I did know what it meant i don't know how or what the code is to link my address bar to the custom search engine that was in the example

Comment: The simplest possible implementation looks like https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/253849549be3e35912a39a5c28263a2d5f7bd76b/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/BrowserTabUserControl.cs#L384

Comment: I dont know how to implement it tho